# How to know if one has aesthetic observation "artist-eye"?

Tags: aesthetics

If I am going to start learning design, I am going to ask this question first - "What is design?" But the search for the answer leads directly into philosophical statements and arguments. I am lost then. What I am trying to say is, while searching for the answer in real world, how could I know I have developed that required aesthetic sense of observation. After that how can I implement my learning and experience in designing real world products.

Comment: Not a question about philosophy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can one measure the quality of art?](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/21553/how-can-one-measure-the-quality-of-art)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question about philosophy

Comment: There are question in aesthetics that can be asked, and that are on-topic; but this seems to me a pragmatic question, and therefore off-topic: a suggestion - you might want to have a look through some of Ruskins books, as he was a theoretician of Art - as a supporter of Turner; personally, I see a large part of Art, is in its practise - ie one must *do*: to *know* design, one must *do* design; and one must *look* at it; in a sense here, doing is looking.

Comment: As a pragmatic discipline, you are better if you enrol on a good programme that does design; rather than think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Why do leftists have a broad **set** of ideals and people on the right also a **set** of different ideals?  Why, generally, do women like romance novels (words) in the same way that men like colorful magazines (pictures)?

There are a lot of answers to those questions directly [try Google], but the philosophical point is knowing the context.  If you want to write a book with mass appeal about science, you need to leave out the equations. [Forward to "A Brief History of Time"], but that's just marketing.

What you want is to develop is a feeling for a balance of form, function and target audience, or, as Barnett Newmann put it:

"Aesthetics is for the artist as Ornithology is for the birds."